# Post request via Axios fails while it succeeds from POSTMAN . How?

Tags: javascript, django, vue.js, postman, axios

I am trying to perform a post request with axios to an endpoint on a ubuntu vps(a django backend) . The api responds 201 created after a successful post request. Using Postman, i am able to perform a successful post request but when i am trying it with Axios, I can see the exceptions being catched in the console (i have used console.log).

**Here's how i am doing it via Axios :**

```
.
.
.


axios.defaults.xsrfCookieName = 'csrftoken'
axios.defaults.xsrfHeaderName = 'X-CSRFToken'

// Tried without headers as well
var headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}

axios.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/subscribe/',data_str,headers)
.then(function(response) {
console.log('saved successfully');
// this.isHidden = false;
alert("Subscription succesful !!");
console.log(response)
}).catch((error) =>{
if(error.response){
console.log('1..........Response Error');
console.log(error.response.data);
console.log(error.response.status);
console.log(error.response.headers);
}
else if(error.request){
// This part gets printed in the browser console. No idea why
console.log('2..........Request Error');
console.log(error.request);
}
else{
console.log('3..........Other error');
console.log('Error', error.message);
}
console.log(error.config);
} );
var headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
axios.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/subscribe/',data_str,headers)
.then(function(response) {
console.log('saved successfully');
// this.isHidden = false;
alert("Subscription succesful !!");
console.log(response)
}).catch((error) =>{
if(error.response){
console.log('1..........Response Error');
console.log(error.response.data);
console.log(error.response.status);
console.log(error.response.headers);
}
else if(error.request){
console.log('2..........Request Error');
console.log(error.request);
}
else{
console.log('3..........Other error');
console.log('Error', error.message);
}
console.log(error.config);
} );
```

**Few CORS configurations in my django rest api :

```
CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True

CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True

CORS_ALLOW_METHODS = ['DELETE','GET','OPTIONS','PATCH','POST','PUT',]

CORS_ALLOW_HEADERS = ['*']
```

Here's the pic of the errors in console [This is the console log in browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yJfph.png)

I appreciate if anyone helps .

Thanks in Advance !

Comment: Is the server being hit by the request?

Comment: and can you also check what happens if you try this on chrome, it might fail on the OPTIONS request, that'll help

Comment: No. The post request is not even reaching the server

Comment: @supra28 Here's the screenshot of Chrome logs :  I don't know where OPTIONS in chrome

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/NVme0kk

Comment: pls expand the log for XMLHttpRequest and repost the image

Comment: @supra28 [Here's the expanded pic](https://imgur.com/qeQz0Tz)

Comment: :/ there wasn't much there , seems like a configuration issue, is the request format as expected in the network tab? is the header getting attached and is the data getting attached properly?

Comment: @supra28 Don't know . Where can i see the details you mentioned ? Also , this is what the postman code looks like `POST /api/v1/subscribe/ HTTP/1.1
Host: somecoolsite.com
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: d5bed604-fd4b-bf50-910d-900f34fec6c6

subscription_email=anu%40wwe.com`

Comment: I am able to get successful response here

Comment: but not in the browser :(

Comment: You can see it in the network tab .

Comment: This is from Network tab : https://imgur.com/d2I7z6x

Comment: You hae to click it to see the details, You'll see all your headers and you can see the data at the bottom, you'll need to see if that is what you exepct it to be

Comment: Provisional headers are shown

Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryDswEV2GCStQfkmqu
Origin: http://somewebsite.com
Referer: http://somewebsite.co/?
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu Chromium/66.0.3359.181 Chrome/66.0.3359.181 Safari/537.36



Request Payload

------WebKitFormBoundaryDswEV2GCStQfkmqu
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="subscription_email"

myemail@gmail.com
------WebKitFormBoundaryDswEV2GCStQfkmqu--

Comment: This is what i get in the details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your inputs. 
I solved this issue . The URL in performing the POST request was `http://localhost:8000/api/v1/subscribe` which after replacing to `http://my website.com/api/v1/subscribe` worked successfully.

I was performing with the actual URL :

i.e, `http://my website.com/api/v1/subscribe` in Postman and that's why it was succeeding. Where as in vue I was using the local host which kept giving error . ☺️